# SwiftyJson get value from array in dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, swifty-json

I've been trying to retrieve the value of code for a while now. This is the json I'm getting back from the server:

```
{
    "message": "The given data was invalid.",
    "errors": {
        "code": [
            "The code has already been taken."
        ]
    }
}
```

How do I get the value of "code" with swiftyJson?

I've already tried this but I don't think it's correct.

```
let list: Dictionary<String, JSON> = json["errors"].dictionaryValue
                    
                    
var retunValue = list.values.first
```

Comment: Why not do what you have already done one more time? `list["code"].dictionaryValue`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson if I print it like ```print(list["code"]?.dictionaryValue)``` I get: ```Optional([:])```.  But when I use  ```print(list["code"]?.arrayValue)``` I get:```Optional([The code has already been taken.]) ```. How can i remove the []?

Comment: You get [] because it is an array so treat it like an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the first element of the `"code"` array like this:

```
json["errors"]["code"].array?.first?.string
```

This will give you `nil` if `code` were an empty array, or the JSON isn't the expected structure.

Since `"code"` is an array, it might contain more than 1 string, so you might want a `[String]` instead:

```
json["errors"]["code"].array?.compactMap { $0.string } ?? []
```

This will give you an empty array if the JSON is not the expected structure.